# Modifying field with regex in Mongo and adding it to a new field

Tags: regex, mongodb

I'm a mongo noob and have what I hope is a pretty easy question.  I received a 100gb .bson file yesterday and need to quickly retrieve some documents associated with urls.  Unfortunately, the people that managed the database decided to change the schema for storing urls halfway through its life.  This means that the url field must be queried via regex and cannot be indexed.

What I am hoping to do is this:  regex out some common string between the two versions of urls and store it in a new field called `url_id`.  This field could then be indexed to make for quicker queries.  Looking through some past SO posts i cobbled together some pseudo-code that might do the trick:

```
//pseudo code, i dont know javascript that well.

db.eval(function() { 
    db.foo.find({}, {url:1}).forEach(function(e) {
        match = e.url.match(/.*(domain.com/.*)?(\\?.*)/); //remove http, www, and query strings
        e.url_id = matches[1];
        db.foo.save(e);
    });
});
```

Then I could run:

```
db.foo.ensureIndex({url_id:1})
```

Which would create a new index that would be quicker to query by so long as I properly modified the urls before querying for them.

However, I'm scared at the prospect of running a for loop across 100gb of records.  Is there a better way to do this that I'm not thinking of?

Comment: If each document needs to be potentially modified, I don't see how you can avoid scanning each one (and optionally updating). It will take a while. :)

Comment: rails has a concept of find_in_batches that grabs records in chunks that will fit in memory. If you can't find some way to mass-update, then maybe look for a way to process your file in batches of a few thousand rows. http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Batches.html

Answer (score 0):

Figured out a workaround...

By simply scripting the modification of the input url to create various versions of itself, I was able to run multiple queries on the indexed database and concatenate the results. Hacky but it worked!